# Swift4 Error Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Void' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'

Tags: swift, swift4, promisekit

Using PromiseKit for API call in Swift 4:

```
 let apiCall = ApiManager.shared.fetchActors()
    apiCall.then { actors -> Void in
        self.dataSourceArray = actors
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }.catch { error -> Void in

        }
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(*) -> Void' to expected argument type '(*) -> _'

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147115/returning-void-in-promisekit-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution:

```
func fetchActorsFromApi () -> Promise<[Actor]> {
    return Promise<[Actor]> { seal in
        return Alamofire.request(API_URL).validate().responseString(completionHandler: {
            response in

            switch (response.result) {
            case .success(let responseString1):
                print (responseString1) // should be converted into the modelclass
                let actorResponse = ActorApiResponse(JSONString: "\(responseString1)")!
                seal.fulfill(actorResponse.actors!)
            case .failure(let error):
                print (error)
                seal.reject(error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be the syntax if i need to handle generic "Model class"/<T> and not just "Actor" model class.

Answer (score 7):

**Use *.done* Instead of using *.then* it will work.**

Answer (score 4):

```
let apiCall = ApiManager.shared.fetchActorFromAPI()
        let _ = apiCall.done {
            actors -> Void in
            self.dataSource = actors
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }.catch {
                error -> Void in
        }
```

use this.In the new version of PromiseKit .done() function is able to do that. Documentation : https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Answer (score 1):

replace `.catch { error -> Void in` with `.catch { error in`

Comment: What about `actors`?

Comment: Same thing i guess. Remove `-> Void`

Comment: At actors section, It gives me error : Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate.