# Returning void in PromiseKit 6

Tags: ios, swift, promise, promisekit

This is what I had working with PromiseKit 4.5

```
api.getUserFirstName().then { name -> Void in
  print(name)
}
```

`getUserFirstName()` returns a `Promsise<String>`. I updated to PromiseKit 6 and this now throws an error:
`Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Void' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'`

This error message makes little sense to me. How do I fix this?

EDIT: So this seems to fix it, but I have little understanding as to what's happening with this:

```
api.getUserFirstName().compactMap { name in
  print(name)
}
```

What's the difference now between `then()` and `compactMap()`?

Comment: Answer is here -> http://promisekit.org/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In according with [PromiseKit 6.0 Guide](http://promisekit.org/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/) `then` was split into `then`, `done` and `map`

- `then` is fed the previous promise value and requires you return a promise.
- `done`is fed the previous promise value and returns a Void promise (which is 80% of chain usage)
- `map` is fed the previous promise value and requires you return a non-promise, ie. a value.

Why that was happend? As said developers:

> With PromiseKit our `then` did multiple things, and we relied on Swift to infer the correct `then` from context. However with multiple line `then`s it would fail to do this, and instead of telling you that the situation was ambiguous it would invent some other error. Often the dreaded `cannot convert T to AnyPromise`. We have a troubleshooting guide to combat this but I believe in tools that just work, and when you spend 4 years waiting for Swift to fix the issue and Swift doesn’t fix the issue, what do you do? We chose to find a solution at the higher level.

So probably in your case needs to use `done`

```
func stackOverflowExample() {
    self.getUserFirstName().done { name -> Void in
        print(name)
    }
}

func getUserFirstName() -> Promise<String> {
    return .value("My User")
}
```

`compactMap` lets you get error transmission when nil is returned.

```
firstly {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: url)
}.compactMap {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, with: $0.data)
}.done {
    //…
}.catch {
    // though probably you should return without the `catch`
}
```

See more info at [release guide](http://promisekit.org/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/)

`compactMap` was renamed to `flatMap` [see discussions here](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/773)